# Handling Unauthorized Access in ASP.NET Core Web App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a brand new ASP.NET Core 5 web application.

I want to modify the `ErrorViewModel` a bit so that I can display relevant error messages to end users.

For example, if the user gets denied access to a particular module in the app due to business logic -- not authentication/authorization -- I want to throw someting like `UnauthorizedAccessException()` in my business layer which is a .NET Standard library project.

When this exception bubbles up to the ASP.NET Core Error page, I want to do a quick check and display the appropriate message e.g. "You are not authorized to access that module".

This is the standard `ErrorViewModel` that comes standard with ASP.NET Core 5:

```
public class ErrorViewModel
{
   public string RequestId { get; set; }

   public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
}
```

How do I capture the exception type and message in the ErrorViewModel?

Comment: About the exception, I would most likely create a new one instead which you control and make the intent clear. The handling part, you would also most likely not do at the controller level due to code duplication. About handling the error, I'm a bit rusty with Web apps (MVC/Razor) but I believe you can use Exception filters for it (if it happens inside the MVC pipeline). Check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters

Comment: Inside there you can inspect the exception type and if it's the one you are after, you can maybe check if it's possible to redirect to other place. The important part is that the filter is invoke before the response is written to the body. For other exceptions, you might just let them bubble up to other places to handle it (most likely you have/should a global exception handler)

Comment: @jpgrassi Thanks for your response. After a bit of testing, I see that any exception I throw at the business layer, bubbles up and automatically creates a `redirect` to the error view. I modified my question a bit to see if I can modify the `ErrorViewModel` to capture the exception type in there.

Comment: I'm happy to create my own exceptions which I've done in the past but either way, I'd simply have to capture the exception type in a property in the `ErrorViewModel`. Just need to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Couldn't you simply inject some middleware to catch all exceptions and reformat them the way you want?

Comment: I think using exception filters as @jpgrassi has suggested is the right way to handle this. Essentially, the filter is kind of middleware in this case anyway. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters

Comment: @Andy I stand corrected. Looks like middleware is the right approach. Here's a line from the documentation: "Prefer middleware for exception handling. Use exception filters only where error handling differs based on which action method is called."

Comment: Yeah I didn't suggest a middleware because I don't write MVC apps, only APIs, so I thought dealing with views (redirect) is better if you do inside the MVC pipeline with exception filters. Anyway. in my APIs I always use the lambda approach like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-lambda. I often put it inside extension methods to avoid repeating it all over :)